# Chrome incredibly laggy, compared to Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Im developing a web browser game and as I am progressing I was seeing a lot of FPS drops during animations - especially draggable in Chrome. I was getting worried ill have to rewrite it and that it is becoming heavy, but when I ran the app in Firefox or even IE11, it runs as smooth as it can, without any noticable lags!

I cant believe Chrome would not handle this type of rendering, is it possible I turned something in console that makes chrome laggy as hell? Some logging etc?

The app uses quiet a lot of opacities, text and box shadows etc etc.

Thanks

Fox

-- PROFILE UPDATE --

So this is what happens

When user opens inventory

```
_theatre('sub', '.character-panel', 1);
$('.character-panel').show()
_loadInventory();
_loadPlayerStats();
_loadEquipment();
```

What I believe is a problem is the _theatre() function. What it does is that it creates a full page fixed div that has 0.8 opacity.

```
function _theatre(t, e, a){

if(a == 1){

    window.paused = 1;

    $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');

    $(e).wrap('<div class="theatre-' + t + '"></div>');

}
else{

    window.paused = 0;

    $('html').css('overflow', 'auto');

    $(e).unwrap('<div class="theatre-' + t + '"></div>');

}

}
```

If I comment the _theatre() function out, the dragging is noticably smoother.

I tried removing the opacity from the div but to no better results. Whats going on? :/

```
div.theatre-sub {top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; position:fixed; z-index:9996; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8)}
div.theatre-dom {top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; position:fixed; z-index:9998; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8)}
```

Profiler data http://imageshack.com/a/img819/8601/jbf2.png

Comment: Have you been developing it in Chrome the whole time? If so it might just be that you need to clear the cache or something from that browser.

Comment: Hi, yes. Oh im stupid, never even considered that. Gonna try it now.

Comment: A couple suggestions. In chrome you can track performance of your JavaScript by using `console.profile();` this might help narrow things down in your code. I am assuming you aren't using jQuery cause you didn't tag it. But if you are using it and CSS border box you need to be careful of how you calculate width. This article explains the issue in greater detail. http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/16/jquery-1-8-box-sizing-width-csswidth-and-outerwidth/

Comment: Im using jquery, I couldnt tag it because of tag limit of 5. I have never used border width() or outerWidth() in my game.

Comment: @Foxhoundn I would suggest removing the HTML tag since it's highly unlikely that the HTML markup is the cause of this or any lag... if you are in need of more tags, that is.

Comment: I removed javascript and added jQuery.

Comment: Just a guess, but try to get rid of the rgba colors, use rgb or hex notation instead

Comment: @Hoffmann I need rgba to be able to set the opacity for only the parent div, not its child elements. But I will try if it helps the problem :)

Comment: @Hoffmann nope, its still the same with rgb(0,0,0) or background:#000

Comment: Could you provide a better screenshot of your profiler? It is hard to see some of the columns and files because of the column widths and FPS box is covering up some of the file names. Also notice how in my screen shot you can see the function `yourCode` and then it shows the percentage used out of the total. This is important to know cause it will show which function is taking up the majority of the processing.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing specifically what the issue is I would suggest you start using `console.profile()` to test the performance of your code. This should help pinpoint the issue.

**For Example:**

```
console.profile("Profile One");

function yourCode()
{
   // some code
}

console.profileEnd("Profile One");
```

[image]
**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/NMbG4/5/

Similar to this you can also use `console.time()` in the same format to track how long a function is taking in milliseconds.

Comment: Fixed my typo and updated the Demo.. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I updated my answer with all the info I could get.